# Zend Studio 8 PHP Core function not reconized (remote projects)

Tags: php, zend-studio

I'v recently upgraded from Zend Studio 7 to ZS 8 and i can not get ZS8 to reconize default PHP5 functions like explode(), split(), etc. It simply says "call to undefined function" and adds a yellow (warning) line under the call.

Google didn't provide me with any information that actually worked. The .buildpath looks fine:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <buildpath>
      <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
      <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
  </buildpath>
```

And the .projects file looks fine too:

`<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>`

Now i'v noticed that when i start a new project LOCALLY it works fine and the "PHP language library" is added fine, but as soon as i open the 'remote systems' tab and right click on a folder and pick "Create remote project" The "PHP Language Library" is simply not filled. Which explains why it doesnt work.

Now the question is, why doesn't it fill up? How do i fix this? (without having to switch to another editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with eclipe Indigo M5 package but I had the same problem. I fixed it uploading the content of the php plugin core on my remote server, and add it as external librairy folder.

The plugin is usualy located there : $HOME/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.php.core

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to `.buildpath`:

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.zend.php.framework.CONTAINER"/>
```

more: [Built-In PHP Functions Are Not Recognized](http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=415)

Comment: Zend Studio 13.5 the entry is `<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one of my projects and I followed the instructions here:

http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=415

Although it's supposed to be for ZS7, they worked for my ZS8.
(It's essential to do the Project > Clean mentioned at the end).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing for me (regardless if it's a local or remote project) is to delete the project itself... but make sure you only delete the project and that the checkbox for 'delete contents' is NOT selected.  then create a new project from an existing directory and continue where you left off.  everything should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a really old question but I came across the same issue recently.

To fix it click with the right on the project and click on

properties->PHP->Interpreter

and enable the correct PHP version for the project

it solved the issue for me

ps. you can do the same at workspace level too